# Variable number of arguments in python

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.x

```
def func(*arg):
    for i in arg:
        print(i)
```

Here if a user is allowed to enter the arguments using input function (python 3.x).

Eg : `"Hello,World,Good,Morning"`

If we want each word which is seperated by comma must be passed as argument...

Eg: `func("Hello",World","Good","Morning")`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you need this function to take a variable number of arguments, instead of just taking a list of arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `*` during function call too. `str.split` splits the string into a list and then unpack the list items into individual arguments using `*`.

```
>>> strs =  "Hello,World,Good,Morning"
>>> spl = strs.split(',')
>>> spl
['Hello', 'World', 'Good', 'Morning']
>>> func(*spl)
Hello
World
Good
Morning
```